# How to implement Pass data between destinations using safe args of navigation component in java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

I search about pass data between destinations using safe args in **JAVA**. There is more example in **Kotlin** but no single line in java so can anyone solve this problem in java.
Or Tell what is meany by ConfermationAction which are mentioned in   [Official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#java).

Thanks in advance but sorry for the bad write in English.

Comment: It does describe everything in the documentation linked, including what `ConfirmationAction` is (in the *Use Safe Args to pass data with type safety* section).